# Name and notation for all arcs from outside a subset S to any node in S in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I have a directed graph G with nodes:

```
1,2,3
```

And arcs: (i,j): from i to j

```
(1,2)
(2,1)
(2,3)
(3,4)
```

Which gives:

```
1 <-> 2 -> 3 -> 4
```

Is there a word and notation for all arcs entering a subset. So if my subset would be nodes {2,3}, the subset would consists of arc (1,2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often notated $\delta_G^-(S)$ (or $\delta^-(S)$ if the graph is clear) and can simply be called, as you said, the set of arcs entering $S$. For instance, see the Preliminaries sections in [these](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2133111) [papers](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1374486).